Variable existence check via $x vs. (Test-Path Variable:x)
In an effort to make our powershell scripts StrictMode compatible, I've made code changes such as:
[ValidateSet("Debug", "Release", IgnoreCase = $false)]
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[Alias('c')]    
[string]$Configuration = $Configuration ? $Configuration : "Release",

To this:
[ValidateSet("Debug", "Release", IgnoreCase = $false)]
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[Alias('c')]   
[string]$Configuration = (Test-Path Variable:Configuration) ? $Configuration : "Release",

In the param blocks of our scripts. Now I'm getting reports of these values not being properly propagated anymore when they are declared in a parent script (I find this practice a bit questionable, but this pattern is too ubiquitous to fix, for now). As of writing this, I don't have a minimum example to reproduce it as I'm still investigating where and how exactly it's happening, but shouldn't both of these behave the same when $Configuration is already defined? What am I missing?

if $Configuration is defined in a caller scope then this works just fine. Also using strict mode isn't the greatest of ideas.

Also note that your pattern of allowing a value from a parent scope to be used bypasses the validation, because default values are not validated via the validation attributes. E.g., setting $Configuration = 'bogus' before calling the script will cause the $Configuration parameter variable to contain this - invalid - value.
